# pressing enter key creates br tag

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am working in a project where I use tinymce editor.When the cursor is inside the equation box,I want to have the cursor outside the equation box on pressing enter key.Now my code works well but when I press enter key,it automatically creates a br tag in the editor.Can anyone point out what is the problem in my code ?
My code is :

```
tinyMCE.init({
theme : "advanced",
mode: "exact",
elements : "elm1",
oninit: function() { loadlistener(); },
```

And the javascript function is :

```
var amedit = false;

 function loadlistener() {
//console.log('load');
$("#elm1_ifr").contents().keydown(function (e) {
    //console.log('key');
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    //console.log(code);
    if (code == 13 && amedit) {

        tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRepaint");

    }
});
var p_parent = $("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("p");
setInterval(function () {
    if (p_parent.find('span').length && p_parent.find('span')) {

        amedit = true;
    } else {
        amedit = false;
    }
}, 200)
  };
```

You can check it on my live site :
[Here](http://beyondthelogix.com/demos/editordemo/demo.html)

And also see [this screenshot](http://beyondthelogix.com/demos/editordemo/screenshot.png) so that you understand my problem more clearly.

Thanks

Comment: Try to return `false` from `keydown` handler.

Comment: @Teemu, thanks for comments.I have put return false but only works in chrome.Can you explain how it can be solved in firefox and IE ?

Comment: Try `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: I'm bad with jQuery, but it should normalize the event properties, hence you can use [`which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) to detect `ENTER`. Also using `$("#elm1_ifr").contents()` looks odd, rather you should find the `window` within the `iframe` (if `$("#elm1_ifr")` is an `iframe` element?). @Popcorn returning `false` should do both of those in jQuery.